# Python Selenium Error "This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79."

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Why am I getting this error? I already tried upgrading selenium via `pip -U`.

Python Selenium Chrome Driver Error:
[image: img]

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: You are getting the error for exactly the reason it says: you are using a version of chromedriver that only works with chrome 79, but you apparently aren't using chrome 79.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update (or downgrade) your ChromeDriver. The ChromeDriver does not come with selenium but you have to download it from [chromedriver.chromium.org](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads). In Windows, you need to replace the chromedriver executable in your PATH (if you have chromedriver.exe in a folder listed in PATH).

You can check the version (major version) you need using Chrome browser at chrome://version/